# Atualização de código no Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Estou fazendo uma transição do silverlight para o runtime, meu aplicativo requer uma conexão com o webservice e justamente nele está ocorrendo o erro, algumas coisas consegui mudar como por exemplo: WebClient por HttpClient.

[image: erro na aquisição]

Answer (score 0):

Sempre uso o [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org) para chamadas de serviços em meus aplicativos. Muito fácil de usar. Exemplo:

```
var urlBase = "http://url_do_seu_webservice_sem_o_nome_do_servico"
var nomeServico = "ServicoUsuario.asmx?op=EfetuarLogin"; // Nome do servico e operação

var client = new RestClient(urlBase);

var request = new RestRequest(nomeServico, Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Xml;


string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <soap:Body>
      ... Dados do seu XML ...
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>";

request.AddParameter("text/xml", xml, ParameterType.RequestBody);

client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
{
    var resposta = response.Content;
});
```